# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Tags: discord.js

What is wrong with what I'm doing? I'm trying to make some code that detects when someone is trying to scam people. That's not the part that I'm have an error with. The error comes when I try to give the author of the message my muted role. Someone please help!

Here's the code:

```js
// mute for 3 hours if anyone is scamming
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.includes("free robux" || "free v-bucks" || ...)) {
    const target = message.author.username;
    const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("1004037957902147676");

    message.delete();
    message.channel.send("@" + message.author.username + ", scamming is...");
    message.member.roles.add("1004037957902147676");

    setTimeout(() => {
      target.roles.cache.remove(mutedRole);
    }, 5000);
  }
}, {});
```

Here's the error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for multiple reasons.

- Your "pattern" inside the `includes` will only every check for the first item. (in your case "free robux", see [MDN Logical Or (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#examples)). To check for all the strings you'd either have to use a regex pattern or individually test every string you're searching for.
- `target` is a string (the username of the message author). If you want to manage the user's roles, you'd have to change `target` to be `message.member`.

Also you declared your callback as `async`, but didn't use any `awaits`.

Your code should look something like this.

```js
const scamRegex = /pattern 1|second pattern|third pattern/;

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.member) return;
  if (!scamRegex.test(message.content)) return;

  const userRoles = message.member.roles;

  await message.delete();
  await message.channel.send('...some warning...');

  await userRoles.add('<ROLE_ID>');

  setTimeout(() => userRoles.remove('<ROLE_ID>'), <MUTE_TIME_IN_MS>);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass a role as the property to `message.member.roles.add()`

```js
message.member.roles.add(mutedRole);
```

Please use code blocks next time you post a question and make sure the format the code.

Comment: This isn't necessary. see: [GuildMemberRoleManager.add](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

Comment: @MrCodingB Yes I know, but without the context the answer to the code is this. Your answer solves all problems so would prefer that anyway.

Comment: No. This doesn't change the way OP's accessing the `add` method, which would be an answer given the reported error.

Comment: Oh.Thanks for pointing out!